# Set locale for java lib on android

Tags: java, android, localization, jar

I have an android app which depends on an external jar. This jar is localized, but apparently it does ignore the user defined locale on android and also the method below is unuseful.

```
Locale.setDefault(mylocale);
```

The Jar does not set locale.

UPDATE: The locale is correctly set, but the ResourceBundle.getString() always revert to default language.

LAST UPDATE: It's a bug on Android, if my locale is it_IT it looks exclusively for Locale_it_IT; and skips Locale_it (which instead is accepted on Java).

OOPS! it ACTUALLY was a bug on my code... android is case sensitive and I created a resourcebundle with locale IT instead of it... shame on me.

Comment: Unless you shed a bit more light on what you want to do, I doubt anyone will be able to answer your question. This external jar may have a line just like the one you show... It is rarely a good idea to set default locale...